# form area control in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set the properties in the text area using class text area.form-control but its is useless.My defined properties of textarea in formarea.form-control is not changing my text in the text area.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .container{
            background-color: aquamarine;
            width:100%;
            height:auto;
        }
        input[type="text"],textarea,textarea.form-control{
          
        background-color:#efeeef;
        width:396px;
        height:48px;
        border-radius:4px;
        
        }
        textarea.form-control{
            line-height:50%;
             font-size:16px;
            color:red;
             font-weight:500;

            }
         </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
       <p>cxfdsgfdagfa
           dsvkbdslkD
           DSNBXCZBV<br>
           SDAKFDSBVLSDF

<br>
dskfdskafbvsakdh  
cxfdsgfdagfa
           dsvkbdslkD
           DSNBXCZBV<br>
           SDAKFDSBVLSDF

<br>
dskfdskafbvsakdh 
cxfdsgfdagfa
           dsvkbdslkD
           DSNBXCZBV<br>
           SDAKFDSBVLSDF

<br>
dskfdskafbvsakdh       </p>

<!--Form element-->
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="form-email" placeholder="Enter Your email" class="form-email form-control textarea border-color outline" id="form-email" >
    </fieldset>
    </form>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please tell me how can I change my activate font properties in textarea and I want to outline outside gray border of 3px in light gray gradient color. Please tell me how can I fix these issues?

Answer (score 1):

`foo` is a **type** selector

`.foo` is a **class** selector

Your element:

> ```
> <input type="text" name="form-email" placeholder="Enter Your email" class="form-email form-control textarea border-color outline" id="form-email" >
> ```

Is a member of the **class** `textarea` so `.textarea` would select it, but it is not of the **type** `<textarea>`, it is an `<input>` so `textarea` will not select it (but `input` will).

Note that giving class names the same names as standard HTML element types is a good way to create this type of confusion so is best avoided.

Comment: hello@Quentin <input type="text" name="form-email" placeholder="Enter Your email" class="form-email form-control " id="form-email" > but now it is also useless.Please tell me where  am I doing mistake?

Comment: Assuming you haven't changed the CSS too: It still isn't a textarea so `textarea {}` won't match it.

Answer (score -2):

Your problem is that you are selecting a class that you dont assign to any component You should use

```
.form-control{
            line-height:50%;
            font-size:16px;
            color:red;
            font-weight:500;
}
```

instead of

```
textarea.form-control{
            line-height:50%;
            font-size:16px;
            color:red;
            font-weight:500;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing invalid about any of the class names used. The problem is that `textarea` is a type selector, not a class selector, and the element is an `<input>`, not a `<textarea>`.

Comment: That isn't what the word means. Answers are very confusing if you invent new meanings for existing words. (`textarea.form-control` isn't invalid and it isn't a class name, it is a selector that doesn't match any element in the document).